# Change version from php 7.0 to 7.1 not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, terminal

I have recently change my php version 7.0 to 7.1

I tried

```
 sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt install php7.1
sudo a2dismod php7.0
sudo a2enmod php7.1
sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml
```

Then when i hit `localhost/projectname`  nothing will displays.. and when u hit `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` got

> phpMyAdmin - Error The mbstring extension is missing. Please check
>   your PHP configuration.

then i tried

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

Nothing change.
finally

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

No change..even i didn't get my project which is worked before.

please help me

Comment: `sudo service apache2 restart` on terminal and check again

Comment: @quickSwap i tried no change

Comment: You mean still getting mbstring error?

Comment: @quickSwap yes...please help me

Comment: What you want to run, phpMyAdmin or your project?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring` followed by `sudo systemctl restart apache2`  followed by `sudo phpenmod mcrypt;sudo phpenmod mbstring;` followed by `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: @quickSwap i want both two..please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow list of commands

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring; #version specific mbstring
sudo apt install php7.1-mcrypt;
sudo systemctl restart apache2;
sudo phpenmod mcrypt; #enable mcrypt
sudo phpenmod mbstring; #enable mbstring
sudo systemctl restart apache2;
```

> **Caution** when you switch version on ubuntu, it automatically removes some version specific extensions. You again have to explicitly
>   install and enable it

Comment: when i hit  sudo phpenmod mcrypt i got WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.1/mods-available

Comment: @quickSwap-again error WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.0/mods-available

Comment: when ii hit sudo phpenmod mcrypt

Comment: Ok, install mcrypt then fire `sudo systemctl restart apache2;` then fire step by step below steps

Comment: sudo apt install php7.1-mcrypt is this way to instal?

Comment: yes. this is the way to install it. or replace `apt` with `apt-get`. But it must work with `apt` too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193742/discussion-between-traker-and-quickswap).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope it helps.